# Jenkins: Generate an email when build takes to long

Tags: email, build, jenkins

I would like to generate an email from Jenkins to my users when a build takes too long.  It seems like I should be able to do this with the stats plugin but cannot.  Anyone doing something like this? Can you share what plugins you are using?

Thanks
-Tom

Comment: If it's ok to have the build failing if it takes too long, the just use `Abort the build if it's stuck` in the `Build Environment` of the job configuration. The aborted job will be notified by email to the users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the [Build Timeout Plugin](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build-timeout+Plugin) to achieve this.

Comment: That plugin can only "Abort the build", "Fail to build" or "Write the build description", but not just send a notification email.

Comment: There's also a [hidden "Perform BuildStep" action](https://github.com/jenkinsci/build-timeout-plugin/pull/10#issuecomment-184333980), but that doesn't help either.